# Why java uses default location keystore/truststore of JAVA_HOME/lib/security/cacerts though I have supplied -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore properties

Tags: java, weblogic, keystore

In my java application I am running with supplied **-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore**  System properties as below.

```
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=/myapp/app.jks -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=XXXXX -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStoreType=jks -Djavax.net.debug=ssl
```

This is my Complete command line :

```
$JAVA_HOME/bin/java -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:HeapDumpPath=/tmp -Xms512m -Xmx1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=192m -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=/myapp/app.jks -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=/myapp/app.jks -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=XXXXX -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=XXXXX -Dweblogic.security.SSL.ignoreHostnameVerification=true -Djavax.net.debug=ssl -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStoreType=jks -cp /Oracle/Middleware/Oracle_Home/wlserver/server/lib/wlfullclient.jar:/myapp/stand‌​alone/lib/asm-5.0.3.jar:/myapp/standalone/lib/castor-1.3.2-core.jar:/myapp/standa‌​lone/lib/myAPP_final.jar
```

But java is not using that certificate from custom keyStore from the custom path. It is by default going to `$JAVA_HOME/lib/security/cacerts` with that I am getting below exception :

```
java.net.ConnectException: t3s://myapphost.com:7500: Destination 10.243.155.222, 7900 unreachable; nested exception is:
        javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: General SSLEngine problem; No available router to destination
```

**When i am importing and adding same certificate in the `$JAVA_HOME/lib/security/cacerts` it not giving any Exception.**

I have refer and this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/663890/how-to-set-up-java-to-use-user-specific-certificates-for-eclipse) and try to configured same things in `$JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security/java.security` and added following entry:

```
javax.net.ssl.trustStore=/myapp/app.jks
javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=XXXXX
javax.net.ssl.trustStoreType=jks
```

Still i am facing same problem.

My Question and problem here is, why java always goes java default keyStore location: `$JAVA_HOME/lib/security/cacerts` though i have supplied and configured my own custom keyStore using : `-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=/myapp/app.jks -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=XXXXX -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStoreType=jks -Djavax.net.debug=ssl`

And if i am importing same certificate in default java keyStore loation it  is working fine for me.

where and what all i need to change to configure different keystore to avoid to above exception.

Comment: Please post the entire command line, and please explain why you think Java is using the default truststore location. I don't see any actual evidence of that here.

Comment: $JAVA_HOME/bin/java -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError 
-XX:HeapDumpPath=/tmp -Xms512m -Xmx1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=192m 
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=/myapp/app.jks 
-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=/myapp/app.jks 
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=XXXXX 
-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=XXXXX 
-Dweblogic.security.SSL.ignoreHostnameVerification=true 
-Djavax.net.debug=ssl 
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStoreType=jks -cp /Oracle/Middleware/Oracle_Home/wlserver/server/lib/wlfullclient.jar:/myapp/standalone/lib/asm-5.0.3.jar:/myapp/standalone/lib/castor-1.3.2-core.jar:/myapp/standalone/lib/myAPP_final.jar

Comment: above is my complete command line.
And I am using : 
java version "1.7.0_79"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_79-b15)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.79-b02, mixed mode)

Comment: I have noticed If i am not having /Oracle_Home/wlserver/server/lib/wlfullclient.jar in class path : 

I am getting different Exception: As below :

ExecuteThread: '5' for queue: 'default', handling exception: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
ExecuteThread: '5' for queue: 'default', handling exception: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
 -  2015-11-20 04:54:02,645 [AT_230SMyApp:AutoLog] INFO

And I have tried below URL as well with respect to custom certificate System parameter
https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1221/wls/SACLT/security.htm#SACLT221 
I got same error

Comment: None of this suggests anything to do with truststores. It all seems to be about network connectivity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After seeing [this Post](https://serverfault.com/questions/106499/custom-trust-and-custom-identity-keystore-in-weblogic-10-3) I have configured and supplied following system properties **-D** option it resolved the problem for me. Hope it will help to others so i am posting it.

```
-Dweblogic.security.CustomTrustKeyStoreFileName=/myapp/app.jks 
 -Dweblogic.security.TrustKeyStore=CustomTrust 
 -Dweblogic.security.CustomTrustKeyStorePassPhrase=XXXXXPWD
 -Dweblogic.security.CustomTrustKeyStoreType=jks
```

I have understood following things which i have kept in Note: of `-Dweblogic.security.TrustKeyStore` parameter.

**Note 1:** **-Dweblogic.security.TrustKeyStore** will have following options and internal interpretation

1. `-Dweblogic.security.TrustKeyStore=JavaStandardTrust` (**We should use when the trusted CAs in the JDK's cacerts, specify this**)
2. `-Dweblogic.security.TrustKeyStore=DemoTrust`   (**We should use when the trusted CAs in DemoTrust.jks and in the JDK's cacerts, specify this**)
3. `-Dweblogic.security.TrustKeyStore=CustomTrust`  (**We should use when the trusted CAs from another keystore, specify this**).

**Note 2**:

Any time if you got below Exception, it means your java application is not finding certificate in the specified trust-store.

```
sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
        at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:385)
        at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(PKIXValidator.java:292)
        at sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:260)

PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException:unable to find valid certification path to requested target,It is telling the same.
```

**Note 3**:
Important things try to cogfigured `-Djavax.net.debug=ssl` for seeing more detail view of logs. Normally without that parameter we wont be able to see more details log.